# Facebook manual logout

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have .net web site which designed for working as standalone application. Due to one issue I was made to perform login flow to Facebook manually instead of calling FB.login(from FB javascript sdk). And because of this I am not able to call FB.logout (because in this case another issue appears).
Facebook support advised me this:
"In this case, you should manually clear the user's logged in session, by clearing any stored cookies, or removing any access tokens or user information stored on our end. You can refer to this page for more information on building login/logout flows manually: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/#logout"
I didn't get this answer. How to realize manually logout workflow?
And I didn't find any examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can check what the PHP SDK’s `getLogoutUrl` method does here, https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/5d0c4865e80e231d48a4571841bd018828fe58e1/src/Facebook/Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php#L156

Basically it just calls `https://www.facebook.com/logout.php` with two parameters:

- `next` is the redirect URI the user should be redirected back to after logout; it needs to be within your app domain
- `access_token` is the valid user access token for the current user of your app

Comment: I added code:

 var permissionUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?" +
               "redirect_uri=" +
               window.location.href;
   window.location = permissionUrl;

And it just redirects to facebook page :(

Comment: You have to add an active user access token. (That's needed because otherwise _every_ site on the internet could log the user out of Facebook, f.e. by simply pointing the src attribute of an image element to that URL.)

Comment: I added access_token. So the url looks like this now: facebook.com/logout.php?next=http://.....com/.../..../...&access_token=EAAFQyVEje9YBAAcvbF7e1YoiWd36URn00C7noE663yyt15DnnZBoNtMaKZBIlhOtdYZCeBbCQXcZBrfIOfRyMBplcu0IhvPgoTlxJPNlCyKsK3WZCZBdpEUIBxCaN5Fd3wlvxheqtBq0ZBZBOni3znLNNnwSKp6qZBaRDFlA56TNGfm0dZAC7KsZAWrPLmiua8ZAYSVPqZC0g4WEU2wZDZD But it didn't work. It redirects me to the site ****.com even not to ***.com/***/*** and doesn't log me out of facebook

Comment: lookup your console. seem there was a access control issue