# Ionic App 1 Facebook logout terminate token

Tags: angularjs, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, oauth

I am developing an app and trying to terminate token after log out. Still have no idea how to do this. I look at this stackoverflow question 
[Facebook manual logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42302898/facebook-manual-logout)
 but it didn't help.

I use ng-cordova oAuth (http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/oauth/) and had to set the return page to http://localhost/callback

The login works but still having problem with the logout

So I tried to do open inappbrowser  to logout url

```
var fbLogoutUrl = 'https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http://localhost/callback&access_token='+AuthFactory.getToken();
$cordovaInAppBrowser.open($fbLogoutUrl, '_blank', options).then(function(event){
            console.log('successfully logged out');
        })
        .catch(function(event) {
            // error
          });
```

It ended up opening an inappbrowser and a broken site that says 
localhost/callback page can't be loaded ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Then I tried to do graph.facebook.com verify my access token that I previously got tried logging out from my device, and still the token is_valid = 1 (Meaning the token still usable FOR THE NEXT 60 DAYS since it's an extended token).

Weird thing is ng-cordova oAuth doesn't include logout function in its documentation at all. And on some forum that I have read simply says clear the local storage of any token and user profile. Which I did and also have cleared the session on my database. My greatest fear, however, is the token can still be used and will be picked up (maybe through brute force) by a malicious coder to access the user's account.

Please help!